# Why do pings to my router take to long? Could it be CPU?

Tags: ubuntu, router, ping

I have an Ubuntu server that is running as a router. The internet will be really slow a lot of times so I checked the ping to the router and it will go up to 1400 at some points. I have top, iftop and a window pinging the router and when the ping is high a process that is called `ksoftirq` is using most or all of the CPU power. Could this just be that the CPU is too weak? It is only an atom processor.

Comment: My guess your latency really is that high.  I would kill the `ksoftirq` process and see if the ping remains high when your internet experiences high latency.

Comment: What does your network look like?  How many other devices are there?

Comment: i have about 25 computers on the network with a bunch of printers. The biggest task that the server has to do is the vpn. There are up wards of 30 or more people getting on the vpn as well. I did some research and ksoftirq is a processor control is used when there are too many irqs. [link]http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/ksoftirqd-80255/[link]

Comment: I have been looking at the network traffic with tshark on the router and i find when the network is slow i have a lot of TCP retransmissions and TCP Dup ACK with wireshark. What would cause this?